# Show ellipsis in DataGrid Column Header vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, ellipsis, dynamic-columns

I am using DataGridView in my Windows Form.

I am dynamically adding columns and populating row values, the issue is, I have set my columns width property to a fixed size, when my column's header exceeds the max width it show the remaining on next line, I have set the Header's height to a fixed size.

I want to show the text ... when the columns width ends.

I am attaching the image of my requirement, I have added Cell_Painting as well but its not working, that is basically for data, 
aslo I have

```
DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used below line in Form_Load event and got my desired result

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.False
End Sub
```

[image]